# Plywood over hardwood underlying a poured bathroom floor?

Tags: bathroom, subfloor, hardwood

[image]In this 1954 New Mexico home, in the bathroom there is plywood apparently laid over the hardwood floors. But it seems to be actually sunk below the 'grade' of the hardwood. Additionally, there is what appears to be some sort of poured surface on top of the plywood and curving about an inch-and-a-half up the walls. Seems useful for a floor that could often get wet. I want to remove the entire thing and begin anew, but the stuff is hard as nails.

Two questions:

1. Is it possible that the plywood is actually below the hardwood?
2. Can that poured floor, whatever substance was used, be easily removed?

Any suggestions for removal, or even for simply resurfacing, would be greatly appreciated. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeQBD.png)

Comment: Was there plywood over the hardwood before you have already taken off?  If not it could be a floor with two sections, one plywood, and one hardwood.  The floor covering looks like vinyl/linoleum (probably well glued on).